# While clicking one of the three buttons cannot disable the other two jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a test. I want to disable two of the three buttons when one of them is clicked and to slideDown() a comment under the buttons when one of the options is chosen. I manage to make comments slide down but cannot disable the other comments when the other buttons are pushed. I'm using jQuery. I have already read many possible solutions but they don't seem to work in my case.

Here's a piece of my code:

```
        <div class="btns">
            <button class="btn" id="q1b1" value=0>A</button>
            <button class="btn" id="q1b2" value=1>B</button>
            <button class="btn" id="q1b3" value=0>C</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="com" id="q1com1">
                <p>
                    comment1
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="com" id="q1com2">
                <p>
                    comment2
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="com" id="q1com3">
                <p>
                    comment3
                </p>
            </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                if($('#q1b1').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com1').slideDown(500);
                    $('#q1b2', '#q1b3').prop('disabled', true);
                }));
                else if($('#q1b2').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com2').slideDown(500);
                    $('#q1b1', '#q1b3').prop('disabled', true);
                }));
                else if($('#q1b3').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com3').slideDown(500);
                    $('#q1b1', '#q1b2').prop('disabled', true);
                }));
            });
        </script>    
        </div>
```

Comment: remove `if` `else` statement, that condition not needed.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra already tried it. doesn't work. in the way you are suggesting after clicking one of the buttons all the other two buttons still work and show their comments too when pushed. i don't want that to happen

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put click event handlers in an `if` condition. You need to assign each button it's own click handler on load and then run the code when the event happens.

To make this as simple as possible you can assign the same event handler to all the buttons then relate the button to the appropriate `.com` div by its `index`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $comments = $('.content .com');

  var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
    $btns.not(this).prop('disabled', true);
    var index = $(this).index();
    $comments.eq(index).slideDown(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.com { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns">
  <button class="btn">A</button>
  <button class="btn">B</button>
  <button class="btn">C</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="com">
    <p>comment1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="com">
    <p>comment2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="com">
    <p>comment3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this approach removes the need for `id` attributes and is therefore infinitely extensible with no maintenance required for the JS logic.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you got any advice where I can find out more about this (books, videos, articles on the Internet)?

Comment: If you're talking about jQuery, then the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com)  is a great reference. If you want to learn more about JS, use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got this structure, but it makes no sense:

```
if($('#q1b1').click(function(){
  //...
}))
```

A click handler isn't a conditional statement.  It doesn't return a boolean value.  Any and every example you'll find on using click handlers in jQuery would just assign the handler:

```
$('#q1b1').click(function(){
  //...
});
```

This structure assigns the function you give it as the "handler" for when that element is clicked.  Which means at any point after this line of code executes, if a user clicks the `#q1b1` element then this `function` will execute.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind click event directly inside document.ready and not inside if/else block.
User comma (,) in single string for multiple jquery selector instead of multiple string separated by comma.
See below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#q1b1').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com1').slideDown(500);
                    $('#q1b2,#q1b3').prop('disabled', true);
                });
                $('#q1b2').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com2').slideDown(500);
                    $('#q1b1,#q1b3').prop('disabled', true);
                });
                $('#q1b3').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com3').slideDown(500);
                    $('#q1b1,#q1b2').prop('disabled', true);
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns">
            <button class="btn" id="q1b1" value=0>A</button>
            <button class="btn" id="q1b2" value=1>B</button>
            <button class="btn" id="q1b3" value=0>C</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="com" id="q1com1">
                <p>
                    comment1
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="com" id="q1com2">
                <p>
                    comment2
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="com" id="q1com3">
                <p>
                    comment3
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#q1b1').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com1').slideDown(500);
                    $('.btn').attr('disabled', true);
                    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
                })
                
                $('#q1b2').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com2').slideDown(500);
                    $('.btn').attr('disabled', true);
                    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
                })
                
               $('#q1b3').click(function(){
                    $('#q1com3').slideDown(500);
                    $('.btn').attr('disabled', true);
                    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
                });
                
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns">
            <button class="btn" id="q1b1" value=0>A</button>
            <button class="btn" id="q1b2" value=1>B</button>
            <button class="btn" id="q1b3" value=0>C</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="com" id="q1com1">
                <p>
                    comment1
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="com" id="q1com2">
                <p>
                    comment2
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="com" id="q1com3">
                <p>
                    comment3
                </p>
            </div>
           
        </div>
```